# compare values (strings) within one column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with twelve rows and two columns, one with the length of a sound (400ms and 600ms) and one with the direction of a sound (up and down). Right now, I'm only interested in the second column called 'direction'.
I want to randomize the values in the column and then compare one value with the preceding value (so n and n-1). For every two adjacent identical values I want my counter_c to add 1, for every two adjacent non-identical values I want my counter_f to add 1.
In the end, I want to have a randomized order with counter_c = 5 and counter_f = 6.
I'm fairly new to Python so I tried to keep it really simple. The code itself works but the randomized order it gives me does not meet my conditions. I'm not sure what the problem is, does anyone have an idea?

```
import pandas as pd

sounds = pd.read_excel('sounds.xlsx')

counter_c = 0
counter_f = 0

while counter_c < 6 and counter_f < 7:
    sounds_rand = sounds.sample(frac = 1)
    print(sounds_rand)

    for x in range(len([sounds_rand[['direction']]])): 
         if x == x - 1:
             counter_c += 1
         else:
             counter_f += 1
```

[that's what the excel file looks like (two columns 'name' and 'direction' with 12 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tjMC.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO ! `if x == x - 1:` seems really fishy. Your code would only increment `counter_f` or am I missing something ?

Comment: could you post a sample of this data? I didn't quite get your description

Comment: x == x - 1 is supposed to mean that element x of column 'direction' is compared with element x - 1, and if both are the same (so both 'up' or both 'down') 1 is added to counter_c. But I really wasn't sure if that was the right way to do it, probably not.
I added a picture of the dataframe to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on your problem:

1. Your algorithm is a hard way to find such distribution. Also, notice that it will not work for any distribution of "up"s and "down"s that you will give to it. If you have the distribution of 10 "up"s and 2 "down"s, for example, it will never converge. I would say that will hardly work for any.
2. Your loop is not reflecting what you have described in terms of comparison. Notice that x is taking the value of the list generate by the range and not by the elements inside of sound_rand. You can fix it using the code below (I have used a loop because you said that you are learning python, but there are many ways to do it more properly using vectorization):

```
counter_f, counter_c = 0,0
while counter_c < 6 and counter_f < 7:
    sounds_rand = df.sample(frac = 1).reset_index(drop = True) # In the coming steps I will operate
    # using the index of this data set, hence I reset it to follow a proper sorting.
    print(sounds_rand)
    counter_f, counter_c = 0,0
    for index in sounds_rand.index:
        if index == 0: # We cannot act when index = 0 otherwise we may operate on [-1]
            continue
        else:
            if sounds_rand['direction'][index] == sounds_rand['direction'][index - 1]:
                counter_c += 1
            else:
                counter_f += 1
print(counter_c, counter_f)
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can write the while loop in a way that the randomized order will actually reflect both conditions? Can I do that with the while loop?
I really struggled with the x so I appreciate your changes to the code. I understand what you changed and it makes much more sense now!

Comment: In the column 'direction' there are 6 'up's' and 6 'down's', so the conditions counter_c < 6 and counter_f < 7 should work. Sorry I didn't mention that in the original post.

Comment: Hi, the code should work fine now with your conditions and the assumption that we have an even data set, but keep in mind this limitation. I have added a few comments to help you to understand each tricky step of the code. Also, in future, when you have more contact with pandas, study vectorization, it is important to optimize your code.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that!
However, the randomized order doesn't meet the conditions most of the time and the counter_c and counter_f are sometimes correct and sometimes not (e.g. it says 5 and 6 and its correct, but after that it says 2 and 9 but its actually 4 and 7). Do you know why that is?

Comment: Notice that the while holds while True, when it is False, it goes out of the loop. About the being correct or incorrect, did you update the code with the last edit version? I checked manually, and the code is performing as expected.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I tried it again and now it works. Thank you!
I still don't understand how the end result can be counter_c = 2 and counter_f = 9. The counter_c condition is true but the counter_f one is not. I thought that the 'and' between both conditions means that both have to be true for the loop to stop?